# Camera Actor Instanced Unreal Engine

Tags: camera, unreal-engine4

When starting a new project with no default mode (essentially all default blueprints) a camera spawns at play on the origin. This camera is called CameraActor_0. I have no idea what spawns it and it actually complicates my game by switching to this camera when adding functionality to the blueprints. I wish to know where this camera is being spawned so I may prevent it from spawning or reference it so I can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreal assumes every scene has a camera. If it doesn't find one, it creates one. If you make a Pawn with camera, CameraActor_0 should go away.